# Flexiblesearch error: missing values

Tags: mysql, e-commerce, sap-commerce-cloud

Hybris Console :

```
ERROR [hybrisHTTP19] [FlexibleSearch] Flexiblesearch error: missing values for [emailId, productCode], got {13=8796135981138, issent=false, productcode =0100, emailid ='hybrisa@gmail.com'}
ERROR [hybrisHTTP19] [FlexibleSearch] query was 'SELECT {p:pk} FROM {NotifyStock AS p} WHERE {p:status}=?isSent AND {p:productId}=?productCode AND {p:emailId}=?emailId '
ERROR [hybrisHTTP19] [FlexibleSearch] translated query was: SELECT  item_t0.PK  FROM notifystock item_t0 WHERE ( item_t0.p_status =? AND  item_t0.p_productid =? AND  item_t0.p_emailid =?) AND (item_t0.TypePkString=? )
Aug 31, 2015 6:51:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [DispatcherServlet] in context with path [/store] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.search.exceptions.FlexibleSearchException: missing values for [emailId, productCode], got {13=8796135981138, issent=false, productcode =0100, emailid ='hybrisa@gmail.com'}] with root cause
de.hybris.platform.jalo.flexiblesearch.FlexibleSearchException: missing values for [emailId, productCode], got {13=8796135981138, issent=false, productcode =0100, emailid ='hybrisa@gmail.com'}[HY-0]
        at de.hybris.platform.persistence.flexiblesearch.TranslatedQuery.removeUnusedValues(TranslatedQuery.java:274)
        at de.hybris.platform.jalo.flexiblesearch.FlexibleSearch.search(FlexibleSearch.java:1423)
        at de.hybris.platform.jalo.flexiblesearch.FlexibleSearch.search(FlexibleSearch.java:1627)
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.search.impl.DefaultFlexibleSearchService$2.execute(DefaultFlexibleSearchService.java:374)
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.search.impl.DefaultFlexibleSearchService$2.execute(DefaultFlexibleSearchService.java:1)
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.session.impl.DefaultSessionService.executeInLocalView(DefaultSessionService.java:88)
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.search.impl.DefaultFlexibleSearchService.getJaloResult(DefaultFlexibleSearchService.java:363)
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.search.impl.DefaultFlexibleSearchService.search(DefaultFlexibleSearchService.java:164)
        at de.hybris.merchandise.core.notifystock.NotifyStockServices.isAlreadyExists(NotifyStockServices.java:118)
        at de.hybris.merchandise.facades.NotifyStock.impl.NotifyStockFacadeImpl.isAlreadyExists(NotifyStockFacadeImpl.java:51)
        at de.hybris.merchandise.storefront.controllers.misc.AddToCartController.verifyEmail(AddToCartController.java:132)
```

Working Query in HAC :

```
  select {p:PK} From {NotifyStock AS p} WHERE {p:status}=0 AND {p:productId}=0100 AND {p:emailId}='ertsergt@gmail.com'
```

Flexiblesearch Query(Not working):

```
    final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("SELECT {p:").append(ItemModel.PK).append("} ");
        builder.append("FROM {").append(NotifyStockModel._TYPECODE).append(" AS p} ");
        builder.append("WHERE ").append("{p:").append(NotifyStockModel.STATUS).append("}").append("=?isSent ");
        builder.append("AND ").append("{p:").append(NotifyStockModel.PRODUCTID).append("}").append("=?productCode ");
        builder.append("AND ").append("{p:").append(NotifyStockModel.EMAILID).append("}").append("=?emailId ");



        final String email = "\'" + notifyStockModel.getEmailId() + "\'";
        final FlexibleSearchQuery query = new FlexibleSearchQuery(builder.toString());
        query.setNeedTotal(true);
        query.addQueryParameter("isSent", Boolean.FALSE);
        query.addQueryParameter("productCode ", notifyStockModel.getProductId());
        query.addQueryParameter("emailId ", email);
```

When i Fire the above Query in HAC the query is working fine but when i fired the same query using flexible search i am getting some flexiblesarch exception.Can anyone tell me what is the Mistake in my flexible search query?Any help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 2):

Adding to what Shresht has answered, always make it a habit to use the field name constants in the parameter map as well.

Example :

query.addQueryParameter(NotifyStockModel.PRODUCTID, notifyStockModel.getProductId());
query.addQueryParameter(NotifyStockModel.EMAILID, email);

The above syntax will never lead to issues. Also for such direct matching queries, I suggest you use flexible search's below method :

flexibleSearchService.getModelByExample(example)

This results in a more maintainable code. Check the wiki for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are giving extra space while adding query parameter for `productCode` and `emailId` in FlexibleSearchQuery. That's why you are getting missing values for [emailId, productCode] error.

Replace this

```
 query.addQueryParameter("productCode ", notifyStockModel.getProductId()); // extra space after productCode
 query.addQueryParameter("emailId ", email); // extra space after emailId
```

with

```
query.addQueryParameter("productCode", notifyStockModel.getProductId());
query.addQueryParameter("emailId", email);
```

Hope this will fix your problem.